# Using Kotlin to update ActionBar in Android RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerViewAdapter for a shopping cart application written in Kotlin.  When users change the quantity of items in their cart I would like to update the title of the ActionBar with the current cart total.

I've looked at various code using callbacks, listeners, and passing context to try to access the ActionBar from the RecyclerViewAdapter but I don't know if these are applicable to Kotlin nor do they make too much sense having always kept all of my code within the RecyclerViewAdapter (database lookups, writes, CardView updates, etc.)

Here is the highly abbreviated code for my calling code and the RecyclerViewAdapter (but I hope that I have all of the important components):

```
class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(private val itemArray: MutableList<ItemObject>, private val contextABC: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        private val cardViewAdd: Button

        init {
            cardViewAdd = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.cardview_item_Add) as Button

            // Add one to Qty Ordered
            cardViewAdd.setOnClickListener { updateItemQty(adapterPosition, itemArray[adapterPosition].qtyOrdered + 1, v) }
        }
    }

private fun updateItemQty(arrayPosition: Int, pQtyOrdered: Int, v: View) {
            itemArray[arrayPosition].qtyOrdered = pQtyOrdered
            notifyItemChanged(arrayPosition)
    }
}
```

```
class CartActivity : BaseActivity() {
    internal var cartItemsList: MutableList<ItemObject> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_master)

        cartItemsList = DatabaseAdapter.cartItems
        cart_RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        cart_RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvAdapter = ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(cartItemsList, this)
        cart_RecyclerView.adapter = rvAdapter
    }
}
```

Can anyone get me going in the correct direction?  I certainly appreciate the help!

[Edit]
With the great help of Birju Vachhani, here is my working code:

```
class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(private val itemArray: MutableList<ItemObject>,
    private val contextABC: Context, val updateActionBarTitle: (ItemObject) -> Unit = {})
 : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        private val cardViewAdd: Button

        init {
            cardViewAdd = v.findViewById<View>(R.id.cardview_item_Add) as Button

            // Add one to Qty Ordered
            cardViewAdd.setOnClickListener { updateItemQty(adapterPosition, itemArray[adapterPosition].qtyOrdered + 1, v) }
        }
    }

private fun updateItemQty(arrayPosition: Int, pQtyOrdered: Int, v: View) {
            itemArray[arrayPosition].qtyOrdered = pQtyOrdered
            notifyItemChanged(arrayPosition)
            updateActionBarTitle(itemArray[arrayPosition])
    }
}
```

```
class CartActivity : BaseActivity() {
    internal var cartItemsList: MutableList<ItemObject> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.cart_master)

        cartItemsList = DatabaseAdapter.cartItems
        cart_RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        cart_RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvAdapter = ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(cartItemsList, this){item->
            supportActionBar?.setTitle("hi")
        }
        cart_RecyclerView.adapter = rvAdapter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using Kotlin's lambda functions like this:

Adapter:

```
class ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val itemArray: MutableList<ItemObject>,
    val onItemAdded: (ItemObject) -> Unit = {}
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemArray.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.cardViewAdd.setOnClickListener {
            updateItemQty(position, itemArray[position].qtyOrdered + 1)
            onItemAdded(itemArray[position])
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        val cardViewAdd: Button = v.findViewById(R.id.cardview_item_Add)

        fun bind(item:ItemObject){
            // bind your data with view here
        }
    }

    fun updateItemQty(arrayPosition: Int, pQtyOrdered: Int) {
        itemArray[arrayPosition].qtyOrdered = pQtyOrdered
        notifyItemChanged(arrayPosition)
    }
}
```

In Your Activity:

class CartActivity : BaseActivity() {
    internal var cartItemsList: MutableList = ArrayList()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.cart_master)

    cartItemsList = DatabaseAdapter.cartItems
    cart_RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    cart_RecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvAdapter = ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(cartItemsList, this){item->
        // here you can access your ActionBar as perform actions on it
    }
    cart_RecyclerView.adapter = rvAdapter
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll update my post with the working code.